# Generating 300+ images causes the images after the 300th or so image to not show up Python Tkinter

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, frame, scrollable

I am working on a program where the user can look at many images which are in a frame in a canvas to make the frame scroll able. But if I load more than 300 images. After it hits the 300 mark the images after that do not show up on the canvass but it lets you still scroll as if they are there so you are only looking at the Gray background.

1. Why is this happening?
2. How could I fix this?

Code:

```
from PIL import ImageTk, Image as im
from cStringIO import StringIO
from threading import Thread
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import os

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.pack(fill=BOTH)
        root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.closeApp)

        self.images = []
        self.image = "Image.png" #Image is 200x100
        self.temp = ""

        self.create_Browse()

    def create_Browse(self):
        self.tfr = Frame(self, height=25, width=650)
        self.tfr.pack_propagate(False)
        self.tfr.pack(side=TOP)

        self.menuBar = Frame(self.tfr, bg="lightGray")
        self.menuBar.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

        self.menuButton = Label(self.menuBar, font=("Arial", 13), width=10, text="Menu <")
        self.menuButton.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.mfr = Frame(self, bd=0)
        self.mfr.pack(side=TOP)

        self.scroller = Scrollbar(self.mfr, orient=VERTICAL)
        self.scroller.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        self.viewArea = Canvas(self.mfr, bg="Gray", height=475, width=650, bd=0, highlightbackground="Gray")
        self.viewArea.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)

        self.mfr2 = Frame(self.viewArea, height=475, width=65, bg="Gray", bd=0)
        self.mfr2.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)

        self.scroller.configure(command=self.viewArea.yview)
        self.viewArea.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scroller.set)
        self.viewArea.create_window((0,0), window=self.mfr2, anchor=NW)

        self.mfr2.bind("<Configure>", self.scroll)
        self.scroller.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self.mouseWheel)

        def generate():
            num = 0
            count = 0

            while count < 500:
                frame = Frame(self.mfr2, bg="Gray")
                frame.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

                    label = Label(frame, image=img, bg="Gray")
                    label.image = img

                    if i == 0:
                       label.pack(side=LEFT, padx=(8, 0))
                    else:
                       label.pack(side=LEFT)

                    num += 1

                count += 1

                for i in range(3):
                    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im.open(self.image))

        generate()

    def mouseWheel(self, event):
        self.viewArea.yview_scroll(-1*(event.delta/120), "units")

    def scroll(self, event):
        self.viewArea.configure(scrollregion=self.viewArea.bbox("all"), bg="Gray", bd=0)

    def closeApp(self):
        os._exit(0)

root = Tk()
root.title("Byte Vortex")
root.resizable(0,0)
root.geometry("650x500")
root.iconbitmap("Files/System_Files/icon.ico")

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried testing with 1 image, 2 images, 3 images, 5 images, 10 images, etc.?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Yes I tested it with up to around 50 and it worked fine.

Comment: Not sure but I assume that every image is loaded into memory. So logically, your program run slow as it begin to store images in swap.

Comment: How big are your image files? What do you mean by "stop responding"? Are you saying it never finishes loading? Or, that once it loads all the images and the program starts, that it won't allow you to scroll or resize?

Comment: Your code includes an import of Threading, but you don't show any threading anywhere in the program. Could the problem be in the code you aren't showing us? Is the socket code related? This doesn't look like an MCVE.

Comment: @Bryan the threading part that I took out had nothing to do with the images which is why I removed it.

Comment: Please create a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can duplicate the issue. Focus on the M and C. remove the threading import, remove the use of StringIO and socket code, add code that has one embedded image that can be duplicated 100 times, remove unnecessary widgets, etc. If after all that the problem does _not_ manifest itself, start adding those parts back in until the problem emerges.

Comment: @BryanOakley The problem is not with loading the images it is that the program can not take 100+ images loaded into it. I was wondering if you could help me with a way to dynamically generate the images. Like when the user scrolls to generate more images.

Comment: @cdw100100: with a couple of small tweaks to make your code runnable, I'm able to add 500 64x64 images and the UI seems to work, though I don't know what you're doing that makes you think it's unresponsive. Since you can't provide a complete MCVE that actually illustrates the problem it's hard to guess what you're doing differently in your real code.

Comment: @BryanOakley can you show me your code and the images that I am generating are 200x150

Comment: @cdw100100: no, I think you should create an MCVE so we can narrow down the problem. All I did was remove the socket code, hard-coded one image into the program (appended 500 times to the list), and then removed the unnecessary use of SocketIO.

Comment: @BryanOakley I can not remove the socket or StringIO because I receive the images via the socket.

Comment: @cdw100100: you're missing the point of an mcve. I'm not asking you to remove it out of your production code, I'm asking you to remove it from this question. If you can load 100 images _without_ the socket code but it fails _with_ the socket code, then we know the real problem is with the socket code. If you remove the socket code and the problem persists, you've just narrowed the scope of the problem. _that_ is the point of the mcve. Reduce the problem a **minimum**, **complete** program that exhibits the problem so we don't go down a rabbit hole based solely on your assumptions.

Comment: @BryanOakley No there is nothing wrong with the socket code. Because the socket code just sends a large string with the images encoded byte format. Then out of the socket so locally which is the code above transfers that code to a string from the list decodes it then uses the StringIO to make the image. I do not save the image to the users hard drive instead I just store it in the canvas. So I narrowed down to the code that I display above.

Comment: @cdw100100: if there's nothing wrong with the socket code, then you can safely remove it for the purpose of this question, making it that much easier for us to diagnose the problem. You are still completely missing the point of the mcve -- did you read the link I posted earlier?  If you aren't willing to help us, why should we be willing to help you?

Comment: @BryanOakley Sorry I was being stubborn. I removed the socket code from the example.

Comment: @cdw100100: that's not enough. The "C" in MCVE stands for "complete". We still can't run your code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley I changed my code as requested to one that you guys can use. But with this code my problem is that it only lets me generate about 300 images before it stops generating them in the canvas. But the weird thing is that it is acting if they are there so you can scroll but they are not there so you are just scrolling looking at the canvas color. Why does it do this to all the images after it hits around the 300 mark?

Comment: @BryanOakley Do you know why it stops rendering the images but says they are still there?